# What embedded browser is showing ad websites?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have banner ads (mopub with AdMob and iAds) implemented in my app. When I click "Visit Site" on some ads I get a seemingly very nicely embedded UIWebView or browser experience with site navigation and a "Done" button in the lower right hand corner. Tapping "Done" takes me back into my app.

What exactly is providing the embedded browser experience here and how do I replicate it in my app? Is this a UIWebView buried somewhere in AdMob/iAds/etc SDK?  I have already embedded a UIWebview, but I would like to leverage whatever framework and code the Aads are using if possible and provide a consistent experience.

Comment: Yes, it is a `UIWebView`. You have to add the done button, though.

Comment: Thanks... it is not only a Done button, but Backwards/Forwards navigation as well. Guess I was looking for a drop-in solution, although I concede it is not the most complicated of UIs. Maybe time for a github search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [SVWebViewController](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController) is exactly what I am looking for.